# Concept for dynamically saving WYSIWYG-Content

Tags: php, javascript, html

I’ve got a conceptual question about realizing a CMS by myself.
I am Trying to create a concept for a simple backend editor on which the user can enter Text, but can also add some input fields which must be usable. I am trying to figure out the best way to create a WYSIWYG-Editor for either Text, Images, Tables but also Form-Elements.

One part of this realization is the WYSIWYG-Editor, another part is the question how to save the whole page after editing (saving whole site as HTML? Or Saving as parts in a database or what?
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use TinyMCE and [`AutoSave`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.plugins.AutoSave.html).

This plugin adds auto-save capability to the TinyMCE text editor to rescue content inadvertently lost. By using localStorage.

You can check out more information from the description page.

Comment: I thought about something like TinyMCE :). 
But there is actually no Support for Form-Fields (I also want to offer special form elements to the User), so I would have to write an extension to tinyMCE. Is this simple enough, or would it make sense to switch to another product?

Comment: There are a lot of plugins for TinyMCE to make it rich and competing. `No support for Form-Fields` What do you mean by this? Form Fields as in?

Comment: I just want to provide functionality for dynamic form pages, just as a register form which gets created dynamically (by editing a new Page with tinyMCE and then press a button to insert a text box for username and a password field and a submit button, and so on)

Comment: I want to create a CMS where the admin can click a form together without coding (e.g. A contact form). He must write the description on the top and then add some input fields to the page. For this last process, I'd have to extend TinyMCE.

Comment: @Florian Oh, designing forms using TinyMCE? i.e., creating the input fields, textarea and all using TinyMCE? Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly ;) just as a perfect CMS should be able to ;)

Comment: Ah! :P That would be tough to do with TinyMCE. But, will try to get an alternate and update my answer. :)

Comment: Did you find any other way of doing this?

Comment: Yeah I just got one. Forgot to update this thread. http://www.fulcrumwebtech.com/form-builder-quiz-generator.php

Answer (score 1):

tinyMCE + jquery will do the job on the client side. 
tinyMCE represents it's content as a HTML + base64 encoded images, so you should save that in the database into a LONGTEXT column type (long because when there are images presented, simple TEXT's capacity will not be sufficient)

good practice is when the controller on the server side is REST enabled, so you can easily POST/PUT/DELETE tiny's content via jquery's ajax handler

Comment: I thought about something like TinyMCE :). 
But there is actually no Support for Form-Fields (I also want to offer special form elements to the User), so I would have to write an extension to tinyMCE. Is this simple enough, or would it make sense to switch to another product?